# span.style.textAlign not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a function that allows a user to align highlighted/selected text right/left/center, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
function doCenter() {
    {
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.textAlign = "center";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
    }
}
```

I've tried this with a separate function that does the same thing, except it highlights the words instead of aligning them, and it works:

```
function highlighter() {
    {
        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the first code?

Comment: Have you tried using a div instead of a span?

Comment: text align center only works on child elements so doing it on a span is no use unless the span is a block or inline block element.  It starts off as an inline element, which means it is as wide as the text inside it (in effect, this means that the text inside the span will already be centered).  If you are wanting to center the span, then apply the centering to the parent element

Comment: I replaced span with div, it's working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`span` is an inline element whereas only block elements may have their child content aligned. Either use `div` or `p` instead of a `span`, or set

```
span.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: See also an article at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align. Quote: "The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent *block* element"